# How to ignore "access to an undefined property" using PHPStan and Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpstan

I am using Laravel 10 + PHPStan.

When I use Resource with the Laravel code, then PHPStan sends me this error:

```
18     Access to an undefined property App\Http\Resources\LocationResource::$id.
19     Access to an undefined property App\Http\Resources\LocationResource::$name.
20     Access to an undefined property App\Http\Resources\LocationResource::$comment.
21     Access to an undefined property App\Http\Resources\LocationResource::$library_id.
22     Access to an undefined property App\Http\Resources\LocationResource::$created_at.
```

I know I can solve this issue with some annotations. But I do not want to use that.
I prefer use the **phpstan.neon** file and declare inside which error phpstan must ignore. See the [documentation here](https://phpstan.org/user-guide/ignoring-errors).

So my phpstan.neon file looks like that:

```
parameters:
paths:
    - app/
ignoreErrors:
    - '#Call to an undefined method [a-zA-Z0-9\\_::]#'
    - '#Access to an undefined property App\\Http\\Resources\\[a-zA-Z0-9]::#'
```

It is the second 'ignoreErrors' line which is not correct.

Which regex I must enter in this conf file to ignore these kinds of errors?

Comment: Because it is an API Resource, I would add `@mixin` to the class definition, usage is `@mixin CLASS`, doing so will help with `$this->property`, the IDE will understand it

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution , add this line in the phpstan.neon file in the "ignoreErrors" section :

```
# to ignore these errors :  Access to an undefined property App\Http\Resources\LocationResource::$id.
        - '#Access to an undefined property App\\Http\\Resources\\[a-zA-Z0-9::a-zA-Z]#'
```

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the errors is not a solution.

Add `@mixin` to the **Resource** class with the related model:

```php
/**
 * @mixin \App\Models\Location
 */
class LocationResource extends JsonResource
{
//...
```